# What is the $\dim(R(T))$

Tags: linear-algebra

$Question$: If T: $\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$ and $\dim(N(T)) = 2$, then $\dim(R(T)) = $?

This was a quiz question that I recently faced. My answer was 3. My thought process with this question was that since $\dim(N(T)) = 2$ we know that the null space is spanned by two vectors. Since our transformation is mapping into $\mathbb{R}^5$, then there must be 3 linearly independent column vectors. And since the $\dim(R(T))$ is equal to the $\dim(C(T))$^T$, then there must be 3 vectors in the $\dim(R(T))$. However, my answer was incorrect. What piece of information am I missing and where does my confusion lye? Is the dimension not always well defined?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "well known fact" from linear algebra states that
$$
\dim \mathbb R^4 = \dim R(T) + \dim N(T).
$$
You can prove that by applying Gauss elimination to a matrix representation of $T.$

So, the answer to your particular question is $\dim R(T) = 2.$

Comment: I guess my confusion is why we are considering $\mathbb{R}^4$ and not $\mathbb{R}^5$ when determining the dim R(T).

Comment: Actually, I see. It's by definition of the rank-nullity theorem.